# How do some programs draw smooth lines?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 2d

As you know, when we use usual line drawing methods, we use such code (I'm not speaking about a specific programming language. I'm just speaking about what do we do.):

```
line(point1,point2)
```

Or something like that.

I'm sure that you have seen that when we draw a **diagonal** line with these usual methods, the line won't be smooth. For example, if you go to windows paint and set line width to minimum, then try to draw a diagonal line, you'll see breaks in the line. But, in some programs like Photoshop, Corel DRAW, when you draw a diagonal line, it is very smooth and you can't see the breaks.
If you take a closer look at pixels, you'll see what causes that:

https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=6D7B572F0E7DEFED&resid=6D7B572F0E7DEFED%21115&authkey=AMgqS95hWkp-e5w

I know that the light-color pixels cause the smoothness.

Okay, can you tell me what algorithm do I need to do that?

Simply, plz.

Comment: I think "anti-aliasing" is the general name for this effect, but there may be more specific algorithm to do this when drawing lines.

Comment: Anti Aliasing should be your algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm) is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply a **Anti-Aliasing algorithm**

Anti-aliasing refers to a number of techniques to combat the problems of aliasing in a sampled signal such as a digital image.
 Specifically, it may refer to:

- Anti-aliasing filter, a filter used before a signal sampler, to restrict the bandwidth of a signal
- Multisample anti-aliasing, a type of anti-aliasing, a technique used
  in computer graphics to improve image quality
- Supersample anti-aliasing, an anti-aliasing technique
- Spatial anti-aliasing, the technique of minimizing aliasing when
  representing a high-resolution image at a lower resolution
- Temporal anti-aliasing, seeks to reduce or remove the effects of
  temporal aliasing

An easy way to implement anti-aliasing is to render your image 4 time it's original size, then store the average color value every 4 pixels (4 square pixels) and render a new image with the average values so it'll be smooth.

Comment: Sorry, but super-sampling doesn't work with lines.

Comment: it will depends of the line's width

Comment: True. I think most line drawing algorithms are single pixel, otherwise they become filling algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

look carefully line drawn in windows paint it fills pixels in line with one color (no shades of line color), hence it won't be smooth.
Smooth line fills adjacent pixels with light shades of line color, so that line looks smooth.[image]